# Android System OnDestroy my Activity in background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem when my App is a long time in the background. After I click the App my activity opens empty /blank and the app crashes. How do I start my activity if the Android system keeps destroying my Activity ?

The onCreate() of my Activity

```
public new TableViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (TableViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SectorLayout);
    }


    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        //this.Intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        ActionBar.Title = Resources.GetString (Resource.String.tables);

        _adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        Pager = FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.pager);
        _tabs = FindViewById<PagerSlidingTabStrip> (Resource.Id.tabs);
        Pager.Adapter = _adapter;
        _tabs.SetViewPager (Pager);

        var pageMargin = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension (ComplexUnitType.Dip, 4, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        Pager.PageMargin = pageMargin;
        _tabs.OnTabReselectedListener = this;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more and add source code of the Activity ?

Comment: @Sreeraj add OnCreate sourceCode

Comment: share the logcat when app crashes. That should reveal the place in your code where there is  a crash

Comment: @AADTechnical But I can not because it happens after 20 minutes when on app runs in the background. Debug is turned off during this time

Comment: You can't prevent Android from killing your PID due to various reasons (it needs memory etc). You'll just have to adapt to the android lifecycle mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement correct lifecycle for your activities/fragments, [check](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

For debugging purpose check developer option "Don't keep activities".